# API to update Scopus data

Tags: api, scopus

We have found that the indexed data in the Scopus database contains a lot of errors (missing articles, citations, wrong citations unlinked citations,...) and we have found only a manual way of sending requests for fixes (that is WEB form or Excell spreadsheet).
I am wondering if there is also an API to either change/fix that data or an API to send the data to Scopus (to get properly indexed)? As far as I found the info there is no such API.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such an API, but if you say they see issues with the data, as you say, there is a process you can follow.  More details can be found here

https://service.elsevier.com/app/overview/scopus/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I as understand there is only a manual (WEB form) way to fix the data. That is very time-consuming, especially since there are a lot of issues. That is why I am looking for a better approach. Too bad to hear that is not possible.
Are you at least thinking about implementing such an API. That could improve your collected data significantly. At least to properly index the data.